# Does __VSFINDRESULT have an incorrect value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-sdk

I'm creating a custom Visual Studio editor and am currently trying to enable find and replace.

In the [IVsFindTarget.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivsfindtarget.find.aspx) method it says to return __VSFINDRESULT.Found and I'm assuming __VSFINDRESULT.AndReplace flags when a find and replace request it called. The issue is that AndReplace is defined:

```
VSFR_AndReplace = -2147483648
```

But the documentation says:

> Returned in combination with Found or
>   NotFound

VSFR_AndReplace is not a valid uint. How could I return a combination of the two?

Answer (score 1):

Try just using `VSFR_Replaced` (which says it is already a combination of `Found` and `Replaced`), for brevity.

As for being a valid `uint`, you can certainly *treat* it like a valid `uint`.  Even though the decimal representation is signed, consider the underlying representation.  In binary, it's `0b 11111111 11111111 10000000 00000000`, or `0xffffffff80000000` in hex.  You can just ignore the upper two words, making it `0x8000000`.  Anyways, since these are used as flags, you can pretty safely just ignore the actual value anyways, and do something like:

```
(uint)(__VSFINDRESULT.VSFR_Found | __VSFINDRESULT.VSFR_AndReplace)
```

Comment: (uint)(__VSFINDRESULT.VSFR_AndReplace | __VSFINDRESULT.VSFR_Found); returns "Overflow in constant value computation". I tried 0x8000000 but it didn't seem to work either. :\

Comment: Can you file a bug on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)?  We may both be misreading it, but it seems logical to assume that you can put those together (and cast to a uint, assuming it is used as a parameter to methods that take uints).

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/574068/-vsfindresult-vsfr-andreplace-has-an-incorrect-value